# What are the upper limits of Aing-Tii Flow-walking

Tags: star-wars

In the Legacy series, Jacen Solo discovers how to Flow-walk, and go back in time. Why didn't he travel back thousands of years? Has it ever been said or even implied that their are limits on how far one can go back in time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of the Legacy of the Force Novels Ben learns to Flow walk and goes back to the time when the Maw was created to contain Abeloth.

The limits are flow walking appear to be in the future rather than the past.  Breaking those limits has extreme consequences as seen in the LOF Series.